# map.find, если в роли ключа выступает вектор

Tags: c++

```
map<vector<int>, string> M;
M.find(...)
```

Если поиск выполняется по ключу, то каким образом мне искать, если я к примеру захочу искать по 1 элементу вектора или вообще как проводить поиск элементов в случае, если ассоциативная матрица, на подобии отображения имеет ключ типа какого-нибудь контейнера?

Comment: Вы хотите упорядочить map по сравнению первых элементов векторов или по сравнению самих векторов, а поиск вести по первому элементу векторов?

Comment: Ну к примеру предикат сравнивает элементы вектора

Comment: Для вектора уже определен оператор <.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то вы можете использовать метод `lower_bound` или `equal_range`, чтобы найти элементы в `std::map` по первому элементу в векторе.
В противном случае, если требуется осуществить поиск по элементу в векторе, отличного от первого, то вам придется последовательно перебирать элементы, используя, например, стандартный алгоритм `std::find_if`.

Например,

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    std::map<std::vector<int>, std::string> m =
    {
        { { 1, 3, 5 }, "A" },
        { { 2, 4, 6 }, "B" },
        { { 3, 5, 7 }, "C" },
        { { 4, 6, 8 }, "D" }
    };

    int value = 3;

    auto it = m.lower_bound( { value } );

    if ( it != m.end() )
    {
        std::cout << it->second << ": ";
        for ( auto x : it->first ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    value = 3;
    std::vector<int>::size_type n = 1;

    it = std::find_if( m.begin(), m.end(),
                       [&]( const std::pair<const std::vector<int>, std::string> &p )
                       {
                           return ( n < p.first.size() ) and ( p.first[n] == value );
                       } );         

    if ( it != m.end() )
    {
        std::cout << it->second << ": ";
        for ( auto x : it->first ) std::cout << x << ' ';
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы следующий

```
C: 3 5 7 
A: 1 3 5
```

Comment: Я написал в общем-то: "к примеру захочу искать по 1 элементу", а если захочу по 2,3, 50..., как поступить?

Comment: @STC Тогда придется выполнять последовательный поиск, например, используя стандартный алгоритм std::find_if.

Comment: @STC Смотрите мой обновленный ответ.